# Power Play: Are the rating bonuses cumulative?

Tags: elite-dangerous

As asked in the title: Are Power Play rating bonuses cumulative?

For instance, rating 1 gives a weekly bonus of 1000 credits, rating 2 gives a weekly bonus of 50000 credits, so do I get 51000 credits bonus when I have rating 2? The same goes for preparation nominations and Power commodity allocations.

Another example: Rating 3 for Aisling Duval provides access to Prismatic Shield Generators, but this bonus is not mentioned anymore in the description for rating 4 and 5. So does this mean that I can still buy Prismatic Shield Generators when I move from rating 3 to rating 4 (cumulative) or do I lose that bonus (which would be extremely weird, IMO, but would be along the lines of non-cumulative bonuses).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When moving up ranks, all previous bonuses of the same type are overridden by similar bonuses of your new rank. So your weekly bonus of 1000 credits at Rating 1 will be overridden by Rating 2's 50000 weekly credit bonus. The same goes for preparation nominations and Power commodities. Every Rating above 3 will have access the unique module.

Comment: I thought as much, just wanted to be sure. Good explanation, by the way, using the term "override" (from a programmer's point of view) :-)